# Is it okay for a field-resolver to write to the database in typegraphql

Tags: graphql, typegraphql

I have a property which, every time that it is queried should return a new value. I need to keep track of this value so I need to save this to the database. This would lead to queries which request this field now modifying the database...

```js
 @FieldResolver(() => String)
  async signatureToken(
    @Root() address: Address,
    @Ctx() { em }: WithRequiredOnly<Context, "em"> //entity manager of the database (typeorm)
  ): Promise<string> {
    // ! Is it okay for a fieldresolver to modify the database?
    const newSignatureToken = uuidv4();
    address.signatureToken = newSignatureToken;
    address.signatureTokenCreated = new Date(); 
    await em.save(address) // Save the new address with signatureToken to the database

    return newSignatureToken;
  }
```

Comment: You're going to get opinionated responses. Normally only a mutation should modify the state of the back end however in one project I keep statistics on some queries so those queries naturally impact data in the statistics tables. I'm curious as to whether or not there's a *correct* answer to this Q.

Comment: At the moment I solved this by just not having a field and users have to perform a seperate mutation to get this value...